# create another instance 'B' after saving an instance 'A' automatically

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i'm using `Django 1.7` with `django_rest_framework 3.0` to develop a restful backend for my application.

***The scenario:*** On the client the user will authenticate with a social network, say facebook. The `token` is sent back to the server which creates and stores an instance of `Social` model.

***The need:*** On saving the `Social` model, I want to *automatically* create and store an instance of `django.contrib.auth.models User` model. The data for the `User` model will be extracted from the social network that the user just authenticated with.

***My approach #1:*** Is there some way where I can send a combined json request to my django backend and create independent `User` and `Social` instances. I think this would require changing the `serializers.py` (given below) code.

For example (request sent to my django):

```
{
'social':{
  'token':'XYZ',
  'source':'FB',
 },
'user_details':{
  'first_name':'sahil',
  'last_name':'gandhi',
  'username':'sahilgandhi',
  'email':'sa***com',
  'password':'password',
  'date_of_birth':'01/01/2015'
 }
}
```

***My approach #2:*** I stumbled across a `post_save()` signal in django's framework. this is my code implementing the post_save() method 
This doesn't require a combined request like **approach #1** but a simple post request that will be handled by `SocialSerializer`

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Social)
def create_user_after_social_signup(sender, instance, created=False, **kwargs):
"""
Automatically create a User instance for every Social signup
:param sender: Social model
:param instance: Social instance that just got created
:param created: is new instance created; boolean
:param kwargs:
:return:
"""
if created:
    social = Social.objects.get(pk=instance.id)

    # get user details from social (ex: facebook)
    payload={'access_token':social.token}
    url='https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me'
    r=requests.get(url, params=payload)

    # create user from response using:
    # User.objects.create_superuser()
```

How to do this if facebook's response is this?

```
  {
  "id": "XYZ", 
  "birthday": "0***4", 
  "email": "sahi***@gmail.com", 
  "first_name": "Sahil", 
  "gender": "male", 
  "last_name": "Gandhi", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_sco*******632440/", 
  "location": {
    "id": "1*****2", 
    "name": "M*******a"
  }, 
  "locale": "en_US", 
  "name": "Sahil Gandhi", 
  "timezone": 5.5, 
  "updated_time": "2015****00", 
  "verified": true
}
```

My current code is as follows:

**models.py**

```
class Social(models.Model):

NONE = 'XX'
FACEBOOK = 'FB'
GOOGLEPLUS = 'GP'
TWITTER = 'TW'
LINKEDIN = 'LI'

SOCIAL_NETWORKS = (
    (NONE, '------'),
    (FACEBOOK, 'Facebook'),
    (TWITTER, 'Twitter'),
    (GOOGLEPLUS, 'Google Plus'),
    (LINKEDIN, 'LinkedIn'),
)

user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='social_owner')
token = models.CharField(max_length=250)
# expires_at = models.DateTimeField('token expires at', blank=True, null=True)
source = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SOCIAL_NETWORKS,)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'user_social'
```

**serializer.py**

```
class SocialSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Social
    fields = ('user', 'token', 'source')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('pk', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'date_joined')
```

**views.py** normal class based view, i.e. `APIView` for the models: `User` and `Social`.

***Finally:***
I strongly feel that the ***approach #1*** is the better way to do it. Just don't know how to go about it. Either way your help is appreciated.

Comment: If you can use something like [python-social-auth](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/), I'd highly recommend it over rolling your own authentication system.

Comment: I'm required to create my own aurh. If you look at approach #1, it should be possible don't you think? A model-less view that handles requests and stores data?